# Windows 11 desktop switching is slow since latest update

Tags: windows-11, desktop, window-manager

Since a recent Windows Update (2023-09 Cumulative Update Preview for Windows 11 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5030310) probably?), switching desktops is much slower.

I normally use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but the same slowness exists if I use the Desktops button on the Taskbar.

Desktop switching used to be instant.  Now, it pauses for a second or two, slides over, flickers the background wallpaper, and shows at the bottom of the screen which desktop I'm on.

It's a little thing, but very annoying when switching rapidly is part of my workflow.  Is there any way to speed it up again?  Some sort of performance-based tuning option, or desktop customization that can be disabled?

Comment: If you uninstall the update what happens?

Comment: Try: (1) Set the background to solid color, (2) Turn off "Snap Windows" in *Settings > Multitasking*. ([source](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-insider-program/slow-virtual-desktop-switching-on-windows-11/m-p/2711164))

Comment: Use Task Manager - Details to see if part of the update, or subsequent malware scan and post-update cleanup, is still running and using a lot of CPU or I/O, slowing *everything*.

Comment: @harrymc Lol, I don't believe it, but setting a manual 'accent color' (as suggested on your link) has made the world of difference and it's quite fast now.  Wild.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: The solutions people propose help, but they don’t solve the fundamental problem. For example, using a background image of the right aspect ratio eliminates the background jitter, but it does not prevent the system from waiting a second before switching. There will probably be no solution until MS eliminate the delay.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For most people, disabling the animation effects does the job:

- Disable
  *Settings > Accessibility > Visual effects > Animation effects*
- Another report said to select from
  *Settings > Ease of access > Contrast themes* ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/accessibility/high-contrast-themes)),
  but this wasn't required for the poster.

---

Other solutions for solving the animation lag come from the post
[Slow virtual desktop switching on windows 11](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-insider-program/slow-virtual-desktop-switching-on-windows-11/m-p/2711164),
where some workarounds were suggested and where
several users have attested to their effectiveness.

1. Set up a fixed Accent Color in
   *Settings > Personalisation > Colours*.
2. Set up a solid Background color in
   *Settings > Personalisation > Background*.

The first setting seemed to have been enough to solve the
slow switching problem between desktops for the poster (at least for now).
Some users in the post have also said that the second setting
helped with the problem.

Comment: These tips helped, but it's still substantially slower than it used to be. Furthermore, now there's a "sliding" animation, that wasn't there before the newest update. Any way to go back to the old way of things?

Comment: This animation was removed since it caused problem, it's astounding that it has come back. I hope that you're not on an Insider build. Try perhaps to disable *Settings > Accessibility > Visual effects > Animation effects*. Another report says to select from *Settings > Ease of access > Contrast themes* ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/accessibility/high-contrast-themes)).

Comment: Woooot, disabling animation effects makes switching instant!

Comment: Kinda a bummer to have to disable all animations for this, but it's definitely worth it. Just feels like I slow down my efficiency to a halt when switching desktops with that animation!

Comment: +1 only had to turn off animation effects and it's instant now

Comment: Disabling animation effects is the correct answer to the question asked; I suggest rearranging your answer to list it first. Before the update the animation was acceptably fast, but after it has become much slower. This change seems to have been intentional on the part of Microsoft. Adjusting the accent color and background color are likely fixes for an animation lag, which is not the question being asked.

Comment: @primo: I accepted and acted upon your remarks.

Comment: FYI this also has other effects. For example, it causes window snap to snap instantly; or causes the firefox new tab favicon to be an hourglass, instead of a loading symbol.

Answer (score 7):

I know that disabling the animations can fix the issue, but if you wish to keep the animations while making the virtual desktop switching itself faster, I got you a solution. But first, I'll explain why this is happening.

**Symptom:** 2 second delay when switching desktop using shortcut (Ctrl+win+right/left) or when using trackpad or mouse shortcut.

**Why this happens:** This is a common issue when desktop background is not the same aspect ratio, and when you use to fit your desktop image to "Fill." You may notice that right before you switch desktops, the image shifts slightly upwards.

Here's how to solve this.

If you don' t mind a pure color empty background. You can change the background to one of the pure colors.

If you want to keep using image background:

**1. Know what resolution you are running in your desktop**

Common resolutions are the following:

- 16:9 (1366×768†, 1920×1080, 2560x1440, 3840x2160)
- 16:10 (280×800, 1920×1200, 2560x1600, 3840x2400)

Some resolutions differ especially with laptops with 16:10 aspect ratios.

**2. Edit the photo you use as your desktop**

- Crop the image to fit the aspect ratio (16:9, 16:10, etc.)
- Its best practice to use the current screen's resolution
- Save a copy and remember its location

**3. Change your desktop wallpaper to the edited image**

- You can do this by *Right Clicking the desktop* > *Personalize* > *Background*

**4. Remove old virtual desktops**

- Click *Win+Tab* to open Virtual Desktop Switcher
- Remove all other Virtual Desktops (because they still use the old wallpaper)

**5. Test if there is still lag**

- Try to use your preferred desktop switching method and see if the problem still persists

Let me know if this workaround helps! Upvote if you think that Windows should fix this stupid weird bug. xD

Comment: Of the built-in wallpapers at `C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\ThemeB` (folded acrylic layers on dark backgrounds), two are 3840×2400, but one is 3841×2400, and another is 3840×2401. Oh, dear.

Comment: “Fill” is not the only problem. I tested every option for “choose a fit for your desktop image”, and the only one that does not cause this issue is “Tile”. This was using a 3841×2400 image on a 3840×2160 display resolution. I imagine that some settings might not produce the issue with some image sizes (e.g. “Center” when both dimensions of the image are smaller than the display resolution dimensions).

Comment: A even simpler solution is to change the background to pure color black. Really Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This command disables desktop switching animation. Need Administrator privilege.

```
./vivetool /disable /id:42354458
```

[Get vivetool here](https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe/releases).

---

Reference

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/16tx25r/any_way_to_remove_virtual_desktop_switching/

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Win10) problem was with Power Toys.
I heard Power Toys in some ways is buid in Win11.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Power Toys is NOT built-into Windows 11.  You are most likely thinking about Windows Terminal being the default terminal handler.

Comment: @Ma ga, can you elaborate on the Power Toys issue?  I have them installed.

Comment: @Brad, Reported bug on Git Hub. https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/29201
You can just turn off FancyZones and everything will be ok, but... without FancyZones

Comment: I turned off Fancy Zones, and there is still a delay before switching. Note also that that bug report mentions a delay only when switching more than once quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
I just removed the desktop with the old wallpaper, and now everything is working fine. There was no need to disable the Animation Effects.