# Speed up virtual desktop animation in Windows 11 22H2 September Update

Tags: windows-11, desktop, virtual-desktop

Windows 11 did not use to have an animation for switching virtual desktops using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> / <kbd>RightArrow</kbd>. It did have an animation for switching using the 4-finger trackpad gesture on laptops, however.

After the Windows 11 22H2 September Update, it now has an animation again, similar to how it did back in Windows 10. However, I've now gotten used to the instant switch :) Additionally, the animation is noticeably slower than the 4-finger trackpad gesture animation - not a lot, but it is noticeable.

Is there a way I can speed up that particular animation without speeding up everything else or disabling it entirely (registry hacks, 3rd-party apps, downgrading apps/components, dark arts, etc.)?

Thank you for your time.

---

Note: There's [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1810772/windows-11-desktop-switching-is-slow-since-latest-update) which describes a similar, but different problem from my "problem" - that post describes an actual problem (flickering desktop), while mine is of a preference problem (animation is slower than I'm used to).

Comment: Slower, as it in takes two seconds before it starts animating?  If so, there's an answer in the question you linked to that solves it:  https://superuser.com/a/1811345/48624  Or slower as in, it slowly swoops over?

Comment: @Brad The latter. Slower as in "the animation takes longer to complete", compared to the speed at which the 4-finger trackpad gesture animation completes.

Comment: Wow, that's wild.  Compatibility with some GPU instruction maybe?  I hope they fix it for you soon!

Comment: You mean that you would like to keep the animation, and only look to speeding it up? Do you have the same background on all desktops?

Comment: If you haven't already, try making your desktop wallpaper the same on every virtual desktop. This solved a lot of issues for me

Comment: @harrymc Yes, that's correct. And I do indeed have the same background on all desktops. Stock background, in fact.

Comment: What happens if you make the background into a solid color and the same?

Comment: @harrymc Nothing changed, it's still slower than the 4-finger trackpad gesture. I think it may be just the animation speed setting, which I'm hoping to find a way to change, one way or another.

Comment: Well, you have discarded the usual methods of disabling animations and/or disabling visual effects, because you wish to keep the animations. Unfortunately, the new animations in Windows 11 22H2 are very badly programmed, so you're stuck with them until/if Microsoft decides to redo its code.

Comment: Thats a shame, but not unexpected I guess. Thanks for the assistance thus far.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1810874/8672) help ?

Answer (score 1):

This command brings back the instant desktop switch like in Win 10, but keeps the part of the new animation to show the desktop name, and does not affect other system animations.

```
./vivetool /disable /id:42354458
```

Need Administrator privilege. [Get vivetool here](https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe/releases).

---

Reference

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/16tx25r/any_way_to_remove_virtual_desktop_switching/

Comment: This has been confirmed to work (at least currently) https://github.com/hwtnb/SylphyHornPlusWin11/issues/40#issuecomment-1850114031