# Disable virtual desktop animation in Windows 11 22H2 September Update

Tags: windows-11, desktop, virtual-desktop

As a follow up to my [previous question](https://superuser.com/q/1811410), as of update KB5032190 the virtual desktop animations now play while switching between virtual desktops via <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> as well. The speed is really bothering me (arguably infinitely so, since going from instant to having a speed means the slowdown factor is infinite) - since I can't speed up the animation, is there a way to disable the animation? I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/16tx25r/comment/k2ktdo1/) post, but the comments suggests that doing so would disable more than just the virtual desktop animations, which I don't want.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1810874/8672) help ?

Comment: @harrymc It does, but as I suspected (and mentioned in the post I linked), it disables more than just the virtual desktop animation. I was hoping there would be a way to disable just that, the other animations are fine / tolerable.

Comment: If there is one, it's not found yet.